# How do I use tel protocol for click to call in qnamaker

Tags: botframework, azure-qna-maker, web-chat

I am using `botframework-webchat` version `4.9.1` and Qnamaker. I have multiple URL links in Qnamaker which are working fine but when I try to use `tel:` to have a functionality to click to call on a number it is rendered as `#` in Qnamaker. I have used as follows:

`Question -> Answer text [1800-XXXX-XXXX](tel:1800-XXXX-XXXX)`

Save it train it and publish and it renders as `www.mydomainwebsite.com/#`

Does Qnamaker support tel protocol or do I need to do something differently? Please help.

**I tried with `tel` protocol and it worked when I put `tel://` and save & train**

Comment: Adding a phone number as an answer using the `tel:` protocol works fine for me (using v4.9.1). My guess is something in your browser is blocking or interrupting the process. When I click the QnA response phone number displayed in web chat, the hosting browser firsts asks me if I'd like to pick an app, and if so, then a Windows dialog opens asking me which app I would like to use (Chrome, Edge, Skype, etc.). I'd recommend checking your browser (or any other relevant) settings.

Comment: Something strange  happened before I got it working. What I did was in Qna maker I used as `[1800-XXXX-XXXX](tel://1800-XXXX-XXXX)` using `tel://` instead of just `'tel:` and it worked and later I tried removing forward slash( just used `tel:`) and it worked onwards. Still I have no clue what made `//` working and now works without it.